# How can I get the ArcSegment and LineSegments from a path?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a path and I need to break it up into it's constituent pieces but my problem is that all I can get from them is a PolylineSegment without the ability to distinguish between ArcSegments and LineSegments. I need to get the actual ArcSegment so I can get the curve data from it.

For example, if I have a path called "snappedPath":

```
   var geometry = snappedPath.Data;
   PathGeometry pathGeometry = geometry.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();
   var figure = pathGeometry.Figures[0];
   var segments = figure.Segments;
   var segment = segments[0];
```

This code results in the segment being returned as a PolylineSegment rather than the Arc and Line Segments I know the path to contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] but my problem is that all I can get from them is a PolylineSegment without the ability to distinguish between ArcSegments and LineSegments.

Well, you use GetFlattenedPathGeometry(). Lets read the [documentation for the GetFlattenedPathGeometry() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.geometry.getflattenedpathgeometry?system-windows-media-geometry-getflattenedpathgeometry):

> Gets a PathGeometry that is a ***polygonal approximation*** of the Geometry object.

So, yes, you called a method to get a **polygonal** approximation of the geometry, and that's what you get. No arc segments, just a polygonal approximation. It should be clear now that if you want to get access to the arc segments, GetFlattenedPathGeometry() ain't gonna help you.

Instead, enumerate the original [PathGeometry's Figures collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.pathgeometry.figures?system-windows-media-pathgeometry-figures). For each figure enumerate the [figure's Segments collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.pathfigure.segments?system-windows-media-pathfigure-segments). And each segment you would then check for it being an *ArcSegment* instance.

I leave it to you whether you want to write it in the form of loops or as some Linq query. While the latter might result in more compact code, the former approach using loops might be beneficial for debugging, especially if you are still in the phase of discovering of how geometries are organized.

If your original geometry is not a PathGeometry, but a geometry hierarchy organized using CombinedGeometry or GeometryGroup instances, traverse the hierarchy of member/child geometries of the CombinedGeometry and GeometryGroup instances to find PathGeometry instances of interest. The documentation for [CombinedGeometry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.combinedgeometry) and [GeometryGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.geometrygroup) will tell you which fields, properties or methods they offer to allow you access to their respective member/child geometries.

Comment: Is there a way to pull the Figures collection from the Path?